# Redux-thunk doesn't dispatch an action in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm new in TypeScript so I'm sorry if the question might sound stupidly, but let's try:
I'm trying to make an async call `getUsersList()`, but the problem is that it doesn't go into dispatch (it doesn't `console.log("hello")`). It worked fine for me in pure React using JS, but in TypeScript it doesn't want to work. What should I do to make it work?

UserActions

```
import {User} from "../../ui/users/UsersList";
import {USER_ADD, USER_LIST_REQUEST_FAILED, USER_LIST_REQUEST_START, USER_LIST_REQUEST_SUCCESS} from "./UserTypes";
import {ThunkDispatch} from "redux-thunk";
import {AnyAction} from "redux";
import axios from "axios";

export const userAdd = (newUser: User) => ({
        type: USER_ADD,
        payload: newUser
})

export const usersListRequestStartAction = ({
        type: USER_LIST_REQUEST_START
});

export const usersListRequestFailAction = (error: unknown) => ({
        type: USER_LIST_REQUEST_FAILED,
        payload: error
})

export const usersListRequestSuccessAction = (users: User[]) => ({
        type: USER_LIST_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
        payload: users
})



export const getUserList = () => {
        return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>) => {
                console.log("hello")
                dispatch(usersListRequestStartAction);
                try {
                        const response = await axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/users');
                        dispatch(usersListRequestSuccessAction(response.data));
                } catch(ex) {
                        dispatch(usersListRequestFailAction(ex));
                }

        }
}
```

Store:

```
import logger from "redux-logger"
import {AnyAction, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore, Store} from "redux";
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk, { ThunkDispatch } from "redux-thunk";
import {InitStateUsers, UserReducer} from "./users/UserReducer";

export interface IAppStore {
    users: InitStateUsers
}

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        users: UserReducer
    }), applyMiddleware(logger,thunk)
)


export default store
```

UserReducer if needed:

```
import {User} from "../../ui/users/UsersList";

enum ActionTypes {
    USER_LIST_REQUEST_SUCCESS = "USER_LIST_REQUEST_SUCCESS",
    USER_LIST_REQUEST_FAILED = 'USER_LIST_REQUEST_FAILED',
    USER_LIST_REQUEST_START = 'USER_LIST_REQUEST_START',
    USER_ADD = 'USER_ADD'
}
interface IActionUsersListRequestStart {
    type: ActionTypes.USER_LIST_REQUEST_START
}
interface IActionUsersListRequestSuccess {
    type: ActionTypes.USER_LIST_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
    payload: User[]
}
interface IActionUsersListRequestFailed {
    type: ActionTypes.USER_LIST_REQUEST_FAILED,
    payload: unknown
}
interface IActionUserAdd {
    type: ActionTypes.USER_ADD,
    payload: User
}
type IAction = IActionUserAdd | IActionUsersListRequestStart | IActionUsersListRequestFailed | IActionUsersListRequestSuccess


export interface InitStateUsers {
    users: User[],
    loading: boolean,
    error: unknown
}
const initState: InitStateUsers = {
    users: [],
    loading: false,
    error: ''
}

export const UserReducer = (state: InitStateUsers = initState, action: IAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.USER_LIST_REQUEST_START:
            console.log("starting")
            return {...state, loading: true}
        case ActionTypes.USER_LIST_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
            console.log("success")
            return {...state, loading: false, users: action.payload}
        case ActionTypes.USER_LIST_REQUEST_FAILED:
            return {...state, loading: false, error: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

UserList:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import * as _ from "lodash";
import {getUserList} from "../../ducks/users/UserActions";
import {IAppStore} from "../../ducks/store";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

interface Address {
    geolocation: Geolocation
    city: string,
    street: string,
    number: number,
    zipcode: string
}
interface Geolocation {
    lat: string,
    long: string
}
interface Name {
    firstname: string,
    lastname: string
}
export interface User {
    id: number,
    address: Address,
    email: string,
    username: string,
    password: string,
    name: Name,
    phone: string
}
interface UsersListProps {
    users: User[]
}

const UsersList = ({users}: UsersListProps) => {
    console.log(users)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (users) {
            if (users.length===0) {
                getUserList()
            }
        }
        else {
            getUserList()
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Users list</h1>
            {users && users.map((user: User) => {
                return (
                    <p key={user.id}>{user.name.firstname} {user.name.lastname}</p>
                )
            })
            }
        </>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IAppStore) => {
    return {
        users: state.users.users
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getUserList
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(UsersList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux changed the [recommended](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript) way of implementing their framework.

You create a [slice](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#create-a-redux-state-slice) in which you define Actions and types for the state, as well as the Action types(if need be).

[Async Thunks](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#using-createasyncthunk)  are also implemented differently, including the way you listen and act on their "types", i.e on REQUEST, on SUCCESS, etc

I suggest reading the links above and the [official GitHub Typescript Example](https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux-typescript)
to understand how to implement things the new way.

I made a small working example using your code in which I call the method that wasn't being executed in your code.

*store.ts* <- I added the logger middleware so it's easier to track what's happening with Redux

```
import { Action, configureStore, ThunkAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import userSlice from "../features/user/userSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    users: userSlice,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger),
});
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

*hooks.ts*

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

*usersSlice.ts*

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

interface Address {
  geolocation: Geolocation;
  city: string;
  street: string;
  number: number;
  zipcode: string;
}
interface Geolocation {
  lat: string;
  long: string;
}
interface Name {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}
export interface User {
  id: number;
  address: Address;
  email: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  name: Name;
  phone: string;
}
export interface USerState {
  users: Array<User>;
  status: "idle" | "loading" | "failed";
}
const initialState: USerState = {
  users: [],
  status: "idle",
};
export const usersAsync = createAsyncThunk("users/fetchUsers", async () => {
  console.log("hello");
  const response = await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/users");
  return response.data;
});

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    userAdd: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
      state.users.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(usersAsync.pending, (state) => {
        console.log("REQUEST");
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(usersAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        console.log("FULFILLED");
        state.users = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(usersAsync.rejected, (state) => {
        console.log("FAILED");
        state.users = [];
        state.status = "failed";
      });
  },
});
export const { userAdd } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

*Users.tsx* <- Call this as a React component in your App file

```
import { randomUUID } from "crypto";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../app/hooks";
import { User, userAdd, usersAsync } from "./userSlice";

const Users = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const users = useAppSelector((state) => state.users.users);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Users list</h1>
      {users &&
        users.map((user: User) => {
          console.log(user);

          return (
            <p key={user.id}>
              {user.name.firstname} {user.name.lastname}
            </p>
          );
        })}

      <button onClick={() => dispatch(usersAsync())}>Call User Action</button>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch(
            userAdd({
              username: "d",
              password: "12345",
              name: { firstname: "vrgve4rg", lastname: "rf3f3" },
              phone: "324e324",
              address: {
                city: "sss",
                number: 12,
                street: "dff",
                zipcode: "d,",
                geolocation: { lat: "123", long: "22" },
              },
              email: "e3d3",
              id: Math.round((Math.random()) * 13344),
            })
          )
        }
      >
       Add User
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Users;
```